# FCM + Ionic/Cordova + Crosswalk - Same notifications received multiple times in intervals

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk, cordova-plugin-fcm

My Android Ionic app receives the same push notifications multiple times in random intervals (mostly around 3-5 minutes) for hours. I'm using the plugin https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm for FCM. But its not about the callback onNotification() being triggered multiple times - there are real notifications popping up in the statusbar. It does not matter if I use https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/ or my node.js server to send the notifications. It's always the same: minutes after the "original and correct" push a duplicate is received and this repeats for a indeterminate time. It's driving me insane and I can't find the root of the problem. Has anyone experienced this problem as well? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My app is using crosswalk. I've noticed that if I remove crosswalk new notifications work as expected and will only be received once. At least it seems to be related. I will investigate this further.

EDIT2:  Another similar app has the same setup (fcm + crosswalk) and is working fine. I don't see a difference that could lead to such a behavior tho :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: There seems to be a bug at the Firebase/Google backend with one of our apps. Creating a new one solved the issue.